# How to check if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\ln(n)}{e^n}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to check if $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\ln(n)}{e^n}$$
is convergent. How I can check it? which test I should use?

Thank you!

Comment: The ratio test is always a good place to start

Comment: Hint: $\ln(n)$ is a lot less than $2^n$.

Comment: Thank you!
I'll get: $$\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n) \cdot e}$$ right?

Comment: Yes. And this $\to \cfrac{1}{e} < 1$

Comment: How do you get the $\frac{1}{e}$? Thank you!

Comment: You can compute the limit of $\ln(x+1)/\ln(x)$ with L'Hôpital's rule. (Intuitively, the point is that $\ln x$ grows very slowly, so $\ln(x+1)$ is quite close to $\ln x$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the ratio test, you can use the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) to obtain:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\;\sqrt[\Large n]{\left|\frac{\ln(n)}{e^n}\right|} =  \dfrac{1}{e} < 1$$

Hence, by the root test, the series converges.